# How to use roboto thin font in qml

Tags: qt, fonts, qml, truetype

I am trying to use robot thin font in QML in Linux.I have install bold,thin and light fonts on ubuntu. Other programs like openoffice shows me only roboto.
How do i get to use roboto thin or light in qml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bundle the font files with your application and then use [FontLoader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontloader-members.html) component to load the version you want and use these in QML.

This component also exist for `QtQuick 1.0` as it was introduced in `Qt 4.7` [FontLoader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-fontloader.html)

Comment: @rkc88 > Yes, just added a link to the proper documentation

Answer (score 3):

`FontLoader` will solve the issue for `Light Roboto` but not for `Thin` as it's not a sported  weight. Remember to call `font.weight: Font.Light` in the text elements were you want to use Light weight.

You will need to repackage the  `Roboto-thin.ttf` as a new font and then import it back with `FontLoader`, (no need for the  `font.weight: Font.Light` call in this case)

Answer (score 2):

AlexB's answer is correct, and has cost me too long struggling why it didn't work.

For those wondering why their Roboto-Light font looks like Roboto-Bold, heres how to fix it:

```
FontLoader
{
   id: robotoLight
   source: "../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf"
}

Text
{
   text: "This text is Roboto-Light"
   font.family: robotoLight.name
   font.weight: Font.Light   // this is necessary or else it'll look like Roboto-Bold
}
```